# How can I search for files shared with a group?

Tags: google-drive-api

Using the Google Drive v3 Api, I would like to list all files that have been shared with a certain group.

When I add the following to the `q`parameter for files.list, an empty set is returned. Can anyone clarify that the `{email_address} in writers` query only accepts user email addresses and not group email addresses?

Is there any other way to list files shared to a group email using the Google Drive Api?

## Edit:

It was working for a while and today it stopped returning results again. It seems that the Google Drive API team has changed something on this?

Comment: I suggest do a get fields=* to retrieve the meta data for one of the files you're interested in, and see what it's permissions array contains.

Comment: The permissions array contains this:
`{
   "kind": "drive#permission",
   "id": "17703153679478172901",
   "type": "group",
   "emailAddress": "Test_Class_2015_teachers_1f1fe926@isdedu.de",
   "role": "writer",
   "displayName": "Test Class 2015 teachers",
   "deleted": false
  }`
However, when I add the `'Test_Class_2015_teachers_1f1fe926@isdedu.de' in writers` in the `q` parameter of files.list, this file does not appear in the results?

Comment: This is a long shot: try with an all lower-case email address. Also try with the v2 api. Are the files in a team drive?

Answer (score 0):

Google must have pushed a fix to the API, since it just started working...